# Limit Sandwich principle

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How can I find:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\Big (\frac{a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}+ c^\frac{1}{n}}{3} \Big)^n $$ if $a > b >c >0$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to use sandwich principle. So I obtain this inequalities
$$\Big( \frac{a^\frac{1}{n}}{3}\Big)^n \le \Big (\frac{a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}+ c^\frac{1}{n}}{3} \Big)^n \le \Big( \frac{3a^\frac{1}{n}}{3} \Big)^n.$$

But, I still don't get the answer to solve this problem with sandwich principle.

What should I do? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The left side is $\frac{a}{3^n}$...

Comment: Left and right sides are $0$ and $a$.

Comment: I believe you could consider $f(x)=((a^x+b^x+c^x)/3)^{1/x}$ and find its limit at $x\to 0$, which is equal to geometric mean of $a,b,c$.

Comment: The "sandwich" approach works only if the lower and upper bounds converge to the same number. What is easy to conclude by replacing all three terms by the smallest or largest is that, if the limit exists, it is in the interval $[c,a]$. \

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big (\frac{a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}+ c^\frac{1}{n}}{3}\Big)^n$$
This is $1^{\infty}$ form, use $$\lim_{x \to t} f(x)^{g(x)}= \exp[\lim_{x\to t }g(x)(f(x)-1)]$$
So $$L=\exp\left[\lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}}{3}-1\right)\right]$$
$$\implies L=\exp\left[\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a^{1/n}-1+b^{1/n}-1+c^{1/n}-1}{1/n}\right)\right]$$
$$\implies L=\exp\left[\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a^{t}-1+b^{t}-1+c^{t}-1}{t}\right)\right]$$
Use $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{a^t-1}{t}=\ln a$, we get
$$L=\exp[\frac{1}{3} \ln (abc)]=(abc)^{1/3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$a=e^u$, $b=e^v$, $c=e^w$

$$\left(\frac{a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}+ c^\frac{1}{n}}{3} \right)^n=\left(\frac{e^\frac{u}{n} + e^\frac{v}{n}+ e^\frac{w}{n}}{3} \right)^n=$$ $$\left(\frac{1+\frac{u}{n} + 1+\frac{v}{n}+ 1+\frac{w}{n}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)}{3} \right)^n=\left(1+\frac{u+v+w}{3n}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)\right)^n=$$ $$\exp \frac{u+v+w}{3}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)=\sqrt[3]{abc}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)$$