# Identity $\lim_{x \to t} f(x)^{g(x)}= \exp\left[\lim_{x\to t}g(x)(f(x)-1)\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, exponential-function

My question begin from this first [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4287753/limit-sandwich-principle/4287831#comment8926101_4287831) where there is written:

$$\large \lim_{x \to t} f(x)^{g(x)}= \exp\left[\lim_{x\to t}g(x)(f(x)-1)\right] \tag 1$$

But if is with $f(x)>0$ in your domain:

$$\large\color{red}{f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\ln f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^{g(x)\ln f(x)}}\tag 2$$

and $\exp_a(x)=a^x$ with $a>0, a\ne 1$, where is the $\ln$ operator and why $g(x)(f(x)-1)\color{teal}{\boldsymbol \equiv}g(x)\ln f(x)$?

Comment: The expression is valid whenever $f(x) \to 1$. In this case in fact $\frac{\log f(x)}{f(x)-1} \to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\lim_{x\to t}f(x)=1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to t}g(x)=\infty$$

\begin{align}
\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to t}\left(f(x)\right)^{g(x)} &= e^{\lim_{x\to t}\ln{\left(f(x)\right)^{g(x)}}} \\
&= e^{\lim_{x\to t}g(x)\frac{\ln{\left[1+(f(x)-1)\right]}}{(f(x)-1)}\cdot(f(x)-1)}\\
&= e^{\lim_{x\to t}g(x)(f(x)-1)}
\end{align}

$\text{since } \lim_{x\to t}\frac{\ln\left({1+(f(x)-1)}\right)}{(f(x)-1)}=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have not read well the question hence. But from the last limit $\lim_{x\to t}\frac{\ln\left({1+(f(x)-1)}\right)}{(f(x)-1)}=1$ is not $f(x)\to 1$ instead of $x\to t$? But $t$ what is?

Comment: @Sebastiano $t$ is a constant such that $\lim_{x\to t}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to t}g(x)=\infty$. In the last limit, if you substitute $u=f(x)-1$, we get $\lim_{x\to t}u=0$, so the final limit becomes $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln{(1+u)}}{u}=1.$

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In that answer, $\lim_{x\to t}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to t}g(x)=\infty$.

We can let two limits $L_1=g(x)\log f(x)$, $L_2=g(x)(f(x)-1)$.

If $L_1, L_2$ exists, then following equation is valiable :
$$
\frac{L_1}{L_2}=\lim_{x\to t}\frac{g(x)\log f(x)}{g(x)(f(x)-1)}=\lim_{x\to t}\frac{\log f(x)}{f(x)-1}=\lim_{y\to1}\frac{\log y}{y-1}=1
$$
So, $L_1=L_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But why do we use  $g(x)(f(x)-1)$? And what is $x\to t$? $T$ who is?

Comment: $x-1$ is linear approximation of $\log x$ at $x=1$. So if $x$ is sufficiently near to 1, then we can use $x-1$ rather than $\log x$.

Comment: Ah, now I have understood! There is a expansion of Taylor to first order.